# Oracle: Need to calculate rolling average for past 3 months where we have more than one submission per month

Tags: sql, oracle

I've seen many examples of rolling averages in oracle but done do quite what I desire.

This is my raw data

```
DATE            SCORE   AREA
----------------------------
01-JUL-14       60      A
01-AUG-14       45      A
01-SEP-14       45      A
02-SEP-14       50      A
01-OCT-14       30      A
02-OCT-14       45      A
03-OCT-14       50      A
01-JUL-14       60      B
01-AUG-14       45      B
01-SEP-14       45      B
02-SEP-14       50      B
01-OCT-14       30      B
02-OCT-14       45      B
03-OCT-14       50      B
```

This is the desired result for my rolling average

```
MMYY        AVG     AREA
-------------------------
JUL-14      60      A
AUG-14      52.5    A
SEP-14      50      A
OCT-14      44      A
JUL-14      60      B
AUG-14      52.5    B
SEP-14      50      B
OCT-14      44      B
```

The way I need it to work is that for each MMYY, I need to look back 3 months, and AVG the scores per dept. So for example,

For Area A in OCT, in the last 3 months from oct, there were 6 studies, (45+45+50+30+45+50)/6 = 44.1

Normally I would write the query like so

```
SELECT
  AREA, 
  TO_CHAR(T.DT,'MMYY') MMYY,
  ROUND(AVG(SCORE)
    OVER (PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY TO_CHAR(T.DT,'MMYY') ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),1)
    AS AVG 
    FROM T
```

This will look over the last 3 enteries not the last 3 months

Comment: `Average = total sum / total count`, isn't it? See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to mix aggregation functions with analytic functions.  The key idea for average is to avoid using `avg()` and instead do a `sum()` divided by a `count(*)`.

```
  SELECT AREA, TO_CHAR(T.DT, 'MMYY') AS MMYY,
         SUM(SCORE) / COUNT(*) as AvgScore,
         SUM(SUM(SCORE)) OVER (PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY MAX(T.DT) ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY MAX(T.DT) ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  FROM t
  GROUP BY AREA, TO_CHAR(T.DT, 'MMYY') ;
```

Note the `order by` clause.  If your data spans years, then using the MMYY format poses problems.  It is better to use a format such as YYYY-MM for months, because the alphabetical ordering is the same as the natural ordering.

Comment: Exactly what I had in my mind regarding avg(), better to use sum and divide by count.

Comment: Thanks, what is AvgScore though?

Comment: @totalitarian `AvgScore` is a column alias, a way of naming columns in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I just wondered way that column was calculated in the first place as it's not needed

Comment: @totalitarian . . . It seemed interesting to me, given that you want the three month average.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's fine. Just wanted to know your reasoning. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify also ranges, not only rows.

```
SELECT
  AREA, 
  TO_CHAR(T.DT,'MMYY') MMYY,
  ROUND(AVG(SCORE)
    OVER (PARTITION BY AREA 
      ORDER BY DT RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))
    AS AVG 
    FROM T
```

Since `CURRENT ROW` is the default, just `ORDER BY DT RANGE INTERVAL '3' MONTH PRECEDING` should work as well. Perhaps you have to do some fine-tuning, I did not test the behaviour regarding the 28/29/30/31 days per month issue.

Check the Oracle [Windowing Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i97640) for further details.

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 22

Comment: What is DATE I don't have a column called DATE

Comment: The trick to avoid problems with number of days in a month is to do `ORDER BY TRUNC(<datecolumn>,'MM')` - that way the RANGE operates only on values that all are the first day of the month.

Comment: @totalitarian, your sample data shows `DATE;SCORE;AREA`. It is `DT` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('01-JUL-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,     60   score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('01-AUG-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       45      score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_date('01-SEP-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       45      score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT to_date('02-SEP-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       50      score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT to_date('01-OCT-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       30      score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT to_date('02-OCT-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       45      score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT to_date('03-OCT-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,      50      score,    'A' area FROM dual UNION ALL
  9  SELECT to_date('01-JUL-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       60      score,    'B' area FROM dual UNION ALL
 10  SELECT to_date('01-AUG-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       45      score,    'B' area FROM dual UNION ALL
 11  SELECT to_date('01-SEP-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       45      score,    'B' area FROM dual UNION ALL
 12  SELECT to_date('02-SEP-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       50      score,    'B' area FROM dual UNION ALL
 13  SELECT to_date('01-OCT-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       30      score,    'B' area FROM dual UNION ALL
 14  SELECT to_date('02-OCT-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       45      score,    'B' area FROM dual UNION ALL
 15  SELECT to_date('03-OCT-14','DD-MON-RR')  dt,       50      score,    'B' area FROM dual)
 16  SELECT   TO_CHAR(T.DT, 'MON-RR') AS MMYY,
 17           round(
 18           SUM(SUM(SCORE)) OVER (PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY MAX(T.DT) ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/
 19           SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY MAX(T.DT) ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),1)
 20           AS avg_score,
 21           AREA
 22    FROM data t
 23    GROUP BY AREA, TO_CHAR(T.DT, 'MON-RR')
 24  /

MMYY    AVG_SCORE A
------ ---------- -
JUL-14         60 A
AUG-14       52.5 A
SEP-14         50 A
OCT-14       44.2 A
JUL-14         60 B
AUG-14       52.5 B
SEP-14         50 B
OCT-14       44.2 B

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

From next time, I would expect you to provide the `create` and `insert` statements so that we don't have to spend time on preparing a `test case`.

And, why `YY` format? Haven't you seen the `Y2K` bug? Please use `YYYY` format.

Comment: Maybe he did simply a copy/paste with his default date format. To paste the example table into [SQLFiddle](http://http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbd1a) takes only a few seconds to generate the data.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the sql fiddle technique.

Comment: One thing to note is that with the `ROWS BETWEEN` it will be average from the preceding 2 months *that have data* up to the current month. Which means that if for example there was no data in area A in August 2014, the rolling average for October would be for July, September and October. If that is not desirable, consider using something like `ORDER BY TRUNC(MIN(T.DT),'MM') RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`