# Calculate a rolling weighted average in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have data with a subset that looks something like this:

```
create table tbl_1 as (
    select * from (
        select trunc(sysdate - (rownum - 1)) as call_dt,
               rownum as calls,
               to_char(trunc(sysdate - (rownum - 1)), 'DAY') as dow
        from dual connect by rownum <= 22
    )
    where dow like '%MONDAY%'
    order by call_dt
)
;

 call_dt  | calls | dow
-------------------------
17-SEP-18    22    MONDAY   
24-SEP-18    15    MONDAY   
01-OCT-18    8     MONDAY   
08-OCT-18    1     MONDAY
```

I then have another table with future dates that looks like this:

```
create table tbl_2 as (
    select * from (
        select  trunc(sysdate + (rownum - 1)) as call_dt, 
                0 as calls,
                to_char(trunc(sysdate + (rownum - 1)), 'DAY') as dow
        from dual
        connect by rownum <= 15
    )
    where dow like '%MONDAY%'
)
;

 call_dt  | calls | dow
-------------------------
15-OCT-18     0    MONDAY   
22-OCT-18     0    MONDAY
```

I am trying to take my future dates, append them to my historical data, and then calculate a rolling weighted average. I am currently doing this with the following query.

```
select  call_dt,
        case when calls = 0 then (
            (1 * lag1) + (0.8 * lag2) + (0.5 * lag3) + (0.3 * lag4))
             else calls 
             end as calls,
        dow
from (
    select  call_dt, calls, dow,
            lag(calls, 4) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag4,
            lag(calls, 3) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag3,
            lag(calls, 2) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag2,
            lag(calls, 1) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag1
    from (
        select * from tbl_1
        union
        select * from tbl_2
    )
    order by dow, call_dt
)
;
```

This results in the following:

```
 call_dt  | calls | dow
-------------------------
17-SEP-18    22    MONDAY   
24-SEP-18    15    MONDAY   
01-OCT-18    8     MONDAY   
08-OCT-18    1     MONDAY 
15-OCT-18    46    MONDAY   
22-OCT-18    24    MONDAY
```

This works great for the first future date for each day of week. However, for subsequent dates, the `lag*` variables are equal to 0, and so the value is off. Here is what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
 call_dt  | calls | dow
-------------------------
17-SEP-18    22    MONDAY   
24-SEP-18    15    MONDAY   
01-OCT-18    8     MONDAY   
08-OCT-18    1     MONDAY 
15-OCT-18    46    MONDAY   
22-OCT-18    70    MONDAY
```

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357071/oracle-need-to-calculate-rolling-average-for-past-3-months-where-we-have-more-t), which seems like it might give me what I want? But the window function keywords used were foreign to me. I also looked at [this tutorial](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/rollingavg.html), but it seems like these rolling average functions assume non-zero entries. Is it possible to achieve these results?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  The simplest method is possibly a recursive CTE.

Comment: Are you aware of the [windowing_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#i97640)? Maybe something like `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '4' DAY FOLLOWING`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using this version: `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am not familiar with the windowing_clause. Can you elaborate a little more on how `BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '4' DAY FOLLOWING` works? Does that create a +/- 4 day window around the date of the current row Oracle is operating on?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Oracle takes in this example +/- 4 days, no matter how many rows are covered by this range.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was able to implement `avg(calls) over (order by dow, call_dt rows between 4 preceding and 1 preceding) as avg_calls`, but this still includes the 0 values that were previously in the `calls` column. I need to find a way to use the calculated value for any row where `calls` is 0.

Comment: Edited the question to include the current results I'm getting as well as the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive query, which takes last `calls` as `lag1` and moves all other `lag`s into the past:

```
with 
  s as (
    select  rn, call_dt, calls, 
            lag(calls, 4) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag4,
            lag(calls, 3) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag3,
            lag(calls, 2) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag2,
            lag(calls, 1) OVER (partition by dow order by call_dt) as lag1
    from (
        select 0 rn, tbl_1.* from tbl_1 union all
        select row_number() over (order by call_dt), tbl_2.* from tbl_2)),
  c(rn, call_dt, calls, lag1, lag2, lag3, lag4) as (
    select rn, call_dt, (1 * lag1) + (0.8 * lag2) + (0.5 * lag3) + (0.3 * lag4), 
           lag1, lag2, lag3, lag4 
      from s where rn = 1
    union all
    select s.rn, s.call_dt, (1 * c.calls) + (0.8 * c.lag1) + (0.5 * c.lag2) + (0.3 * c.lag3), 
           c.calls, c.lag1, c.lag2, c.lag3
      from s join c on c.rn+1 = s.rn)
select * from c
```

`s` - is basically your query, where I added row numbering. `c` is CTE, where `rn = 1` is our anchor, first step. Then we add next steps row by row, 
moving previous values *to the right*. I think we should divide result by 4, but you didn't do it? Hope this helps.

Result:

```
    RN CALL_DT          CALLS       LAG1       LAG2       LAG3       LAG4
------ ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1 2018-10-15        21,5          1          8         15         22
     2 2018-10-22        30,8       21,5          1          8         15
```

Comment: Yeah, the results are supposed to be divided by four to get the average, but I forgot to include that and didn't want to cause confusion by changing it. Your results look right, but I need to spend some time grokking the solution. As I'm reviewing, can you clarify if this solution is dynamic in the range of future dates it handles, or does the solution assume there are only two weeks to forecast? Thank you in advance for this!

Comment: Just tested everything out and this works perfectly! Thank you so much!